# Criteria and Formula expression behaving differently in Approval Process

Tags: approval-process

I am facing a strange problem regarding Approval Process -

If i use `Entry Criteria` based condition like below -

> (Pricing Assistant: Pricing Assistant StatusNOT EQUAL TOApproved) AND
>   (Pricing Assistant: Pricing Assistant StatusNOT EQUAL TOSubmitted) AND
>   (Pricing Assistant: Margin With Pass-Through %GREATER OR EQUAL60) AND
>   (Pricing Assistant: Proposed Contract Price USDLESS OR EQUAL500000)
>   AND (Pricing Assistant: Route to MC ApprovalEQUALSTrue)

It works fine. but if i use `formula based criteria` like below -

> AND(NOT(ISPICKVAL(Pricing_Calculator_Status__c ,'Approved')) ,
>   NOT(ISPICKVAL(Pricing_Calculator_Status__c ,'Submitted')) ,
>   Margin_With_Pass_Through__c >= 60, Proposed_Contract_Price_USD__c <=
>   500000, Route_to_MC_Approval__c = true)

it doesn't work. I don't see any difference between both but still both are behaving differently.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: A "shot in the dark suggestion" -> check that the formula is returning 60 and not 0.6 for Margin_With_Pass_Through__c. Might be an idea as well to create the formula as a formula field and debug it through there to see the value is as you expect.

Comment: it is returning 60

Comment: Did you create it as a formula and check as well? Separate all the requisite parts out into formulas to validate everything then remove them later.

Comment: I got the answer through your above question like 60 or 0.6. please find my answer below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`@pbattisson` comments helped me to find the answer.

Actually `Margin_With_Pass_Through__c` is a percent formula field and when i see the Approval Process Logs it was showing value like 64.3 but internally it was converting 64.3/100 = 0.643 as return type is percent and then comparing it with 60 so returning false and would not entering in Approval process.

but somehow in `entry criteria` `Margin_With_Pass_Through__c` returning 64.3 and hence entering in Approval process.

Comment: Internally, it seems that percent fields are indeed stored as decimal values, where 1 is 100%. The UI uses the percent notation, where 100 is 100%. Formulas act as code, thus using the first data type, consistent with Apex Code, while standard criteria works like the UI, similar to reports.